# compare python dictionary values of type list to see if they match in that order

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashmap

```
prefs = 
{
    's1': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    's2': ["c", "d", "e", "a", "b"],
    's3': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    's4': ["c", "d", "e", "b", "e"]
}
```

I have a dictionary, and I want to compare the values (Type: List) for each key to see if they exist in that order. So essentially I'm trying to iterate over each key-value pair and compare the value which is of type list to the next value to see if the elements in that list match in that specific order. If we find a match, I want to return a list of keys that make the match.

ex: s1 value is a list with elements "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", so I want to check other values with the elements in the same order. So in this case key s3 would be returned since the values match with the same exact order.
s1 value = s3 value because of the elements in the list match in the same order.
return list would be something like [s1:s3], and multiple matches should be returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find matching lists, you could do something like this:

```
prefs = {
    's1': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    's2': ["c", "d", "e", "a", "b"],
    's3': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    's4': ["c", "d", "e", "b", "e"],
    's5': ["c", "d", "e", "b", "e"]
}

matches = {}
for key, value in prefs.items():
    value = tuple(value)
    if value not in matches:
        matches[value] = []
    matches[value].append(key)

print(matches)
```

Which prints:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): ['s1', 's3'], ('c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'e'): ['s5', 's4'], ('c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'): ['s2']}
```

(Note: I added `s5` to `prefs`.)

---

**Update**

If you just want the grouped keys, you can access them via `matches.values()`:

```
print(*matches.values())
```

Which prints:

```
['s4', 's5'] ['s1', 's3'] ['s2']
```

Also, you can do the whole thing in one line if you want:

```
print({value: [key for key in prefs if tuple(prefs[key]) == value] for value in set(map(tuple, prefs.values()))})
```

Comment: so s2 is returned but it does not have a match, do I just assume that if a list does not have 2 keys returned then it does not have a match.

Comment: makes sense. But I have a hard time following after if condition. So basically you created a new hash and converted the values into a tuple. Then you check to see if the value does not exist in the matches{}. But I'm a little lost after that line. Your setting the value to an empty array, but can you explain those lines after the if. How can I verify the code to where if there are multiple matches, I return the 2 keys as a set instead of just returning all the keys in a list.

Comment: I have opened a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935130/how-to-compare-elements-of-a-list-in-a-python-maps-value-and-check-to-see-if-a

Answer (score 1):

First sort by values using `sorted` then use `itertools.groupby`

```
prefs = {
            's1': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
            's2': ["c", "d", "e", "a", "b"],
            's3': ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
            's4': ["c", "d", "e", "b", "e"],
            's5': ["c", "d", "e", "a", "b"]
        }

from itertools import groupby
[[t[0] for t in g] for k,g in groupby(sorted(prefs.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]), lambda x:x[1])]
#[['s1', 's3'], ['s2', 's5'], ['s4']]
```

To print with values:

```
{tuple(k):[t[0] for t in g] for k,g in groupby(sorted(prefs.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]), lambda x:x[1])}
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): ['s1', 's3'],
 ('c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'): ['s2', 's5'],
 ('c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'e'): ['s4']}
```

Comment: @Transhuman how are you printing the values. I'm trying to figure out how I can print this onto a console.